# Table not created with DbContext (Invalid object name)

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I want to learn ASP .NET with Blazor so I try to create a little project with Blazor WebAssembly and an API to make a connection between the front and the database.
My problem is that I have created a first DbContext (with controller + model) and it works well. But when I try to create a second DbContext (with controller + model), table isn't created in database because context.Database.EnsureCreated returns false. (but the first table named DisplayableElements is perfectly created !)

Here you can see Program.cs :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Portfolio.API.Contexts;

namespace Portfolio.API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            CreateDbIfNotExists(host);

            host.Run();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static void CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host)
        {
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var contextDisplayableElement = services.GetRequiredService<DisplayableElementContext>();
                    Initializer.DbInitializer.InitializeDisplayableElements(contextDisplayableElement);
                    var contextUser = services.GetRequiredService<UserContext>();
                    Initializer.DbInitializer.InitializeUsers(contextUser);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
                }
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Here you can see Startup.cs :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Portfolio.API.Contexts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Portfolio.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });


            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<DisplayableElementContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Portfolio.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Portfolio.API v1"));
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see UserContext.cs :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Portfolio.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Portfolio.API.Contexts
{
    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here you can see User.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
   public class User
   {
       public long Id { get; set; }
       public string Login { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
       public int NumberConnectionTry { get; set; }

       public User(string login, string password)
       {
           this.Login = login;
           this.Password = password;
       }

       public User()
       { }
   }
```

Here you can see appsettings.json :

```
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Portfolio;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 },
 "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "Microsoft": "Warning",
     "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
   }
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "ApiKey": "localhostKey"
}
```

Here you can see DbInitializer.cs:

```
using Portfolio.API.Contexts;
using Portfolio.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Portfolio.API.Initializer
{
   public class DbInitializer
   {
       public static void InitializeDisplayableElements(DisplayableElementContext context)
       {
           context.Database.EnsureCreated();

           // Look for any displayable element.
           if (context.DisplayableElements.Any())
           {
               return;   // DB has been seeded
           }

           var elements = new DisplayableElement[]
           {
               new DisplayableElement("software", 0, "Visual Studio 2019", 3)
           };
           foreach (DisplayableElement dis in elements)
           {
               context.DisplayablesElements.Add(dis);
           }
           context.SaveChanges();
       }

       public static void InitializeUsers(UserContext context)
       {
           var toto = context.Database.EnsureCreated();
           if (context.Users.Any())
           {
               return;   // DB has been seeded
           }
           var elements = new User[]
           {
               new User("toto", "toto")
           };
           foreach (User u in elements)
           {
               context.Users.Add(u);
           }
           context.SaveChanges();

       }
   }


}
```

Have you got a solution to solve this issue please ?
If you need another file of my project, don't hesitate to ask...

Thanks for taking the time to read this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update : In fact, I cant' create two DbContexts for the same database. So, I put all my DbSet in the same class like this :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Portfolio.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Portfolio.API.Contexts
{
    public class PortfolioContext : DbContext
    {
        public PortfolioContext(DbContextOptions<PortfolioContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<DisplayableElement> DisplayableElements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you if you have the same problem than me !

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation of [EnsureCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_EnsureCreated) .

In the above test, assuming that no database exists, for the first test run, EnsureCreated will create the database and pass the test. But for any subsequent runs, the database already exists, so EnsureCreated returns false. Maybe you want to use EnsureDeletedbeforeEnsureCreated to ensure that the database is deleted so that you can test its actual creation.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply and sorry for my late answer, I had internet connection issue. The problem is that my table isn't created (if I display the database on visual studio 2019, I can't see this table). Furthermore, the file with my table isn't created in my user folder. So I think my issue comes from elsewhere.